# Can't append EmbeddedDocument on save()

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, mongoengine

Here are my models:

```
class Subscriber(Document):
  service = StringField()
  history = EmbeddedDocumentListField('SubscriberHistory')

  def __str__(self):
      return self.service

class SubscriberHistory(EmbeddedDocument):
  action = StringField()
  content = DictField()
  created_at = DateTimeField(required=True, default=datetime.utcnow)

  def __str__(self):
    return self.action
```

and here's the code, where i try to save the embed into my document:

```
subscriber_history = SubscriberHistory()
subscriber_history.action = 'inbound',
subscriber_history.content = event
self.subscriber.history.append(subscriber_history)
self.subscriber.save()
```

as soon as i run `self.subscriber.save()` i get the following error:

```
 File "/foo/bar/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mongoengine/base/fields.py", line 415, in validate
 self.error('Invalid %s item (%s)' % (field_class, value),
 TypeError: __repr__ returned non-string (type tuple)
```

My code is correct (as I read in the mongoengine docs), but it won't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you first save a document, the subscriber document, make history equals "=" with a list

```
subscriber.history = [subscriber_history]
subscriber.save()
```

Later, when you need to add more histories, you make an update operation/query, you never append to a mongo list field.